# How to change PageBuilder product carousel default slidesToScroll option for various breakpoints?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5, slick

Can someone help me to figure out the following:

Magento 2 PageBuilder product carousel needs to change the default slidesToScroll option for various breakpoints.

I have total 6 items displaying at a time in the product carousel and when I click on the arrow it is sliding to next 6 items. I want to slide 3 items by clicking on the arrow. Please help me on this asap.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as things stands in magento without modifying core script for slider widget located at: `src/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/base/web/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/widget.js`

If you see line 32 in above script: `config.slidesToScroll = config.slidesToShow;` It sets slidesToScroll equal to slidesToShow, so no matter what you passed via view.xml it will stay as it is. You will need to modify both buildSlick and initSlider methods to get this working along with new values passed from view.xml

Answer (score 0):

As Sajid said you need to override `vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/base/web/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/widget.js`

Create a module (I named it PageBuilderCarousel): 
code\YourVendor\PageBuilderCarousel\ **registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'YourVendor_PageBuilderCarousel', __DIR__);
```

code\YourVendor\PageBuilderCarousel\etc\ **module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="YourVendor_PageBuilderCarousel" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_PageBuilder"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

code\YourVendor\PageBuilderCarousel\etc\ **di.xml** 
here we override the xml where that widget.js is specified

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\WidgetInitializerConfig">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="products" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_PageBuilderCarousel/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/widget-mixin</item>
                        <item name="appearance" xsi:type="string">carousel</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

code/YourVendor/PageBuilderCarousel/view/base/web/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/ **widget-mixin.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'matchMedia',
    'Magento_PageBuilder/js/utils/breakpoints',
    'Magento_PageBuilder/js/events',
    'slick'
], function ($, _, mediaCheck, breakpointsUtils, events) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Build slick
     *
     * @param {jQuery} $carouselElement
     * @param {Object} config
     */
    function buildSlick($carouselElement, config) {
        /**
         * Prevent each slick slider from being initialized more than once which could throw an error.
         */
        if ($carouselElement.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
            $carouselElement.slick('unslick');
        }

        $carouselElement.slick(config);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize slider.
     *
     * @param {jQuery} $element
     * @param {Object} slickConfig
     * @param {Object} breakpoint
     */
    function initSlider($element, slickConfig, breakpoint) {
        var productCount = $element.find('.product-item').length,
            $carouselElement = $($element.children()),
            centerModeClass = 'center-mode',
            carouselMode = $element.data('carousel-mode'),
            slidesToShow = breakpoint.options.products[carouselMode] ?
                breakpoint.options.products[carouselMode].slidesToShow :
                breakpoint.options.products.default.slidesToShow,
            slidesToScroll = breakpoint.options.products[carouselMode] ?
                breakpoint.options.products[carouselMode].slidesToScroll :
                breakpoint.options.products[carouselMode].slidesToShow;

        slickConfig.slidesToScroll = parseFloat(slidesToScroll);

        slickConfig.slidesToShow = parseFloat(slidesToShow);

        if (carouselMode === 'continuous' && productCount > slickConfig.slidesToShow) {
            $element.addClass(centerModeClass);
            slickConfig.centerPadding = $element.data('center-padding');
            slickConfig.centerMode = true;
        } else {
            $element.removeClass(centerModeClass);
            slickConfig.infinite = $element.data('infinite-loop');
        }

        buildSlick($carouselElement, slickConfig);
    }

    return function (config, element) {
        var $element = $(element),
            $carouselElement = $($element.children()),
            currentViewport = config.currentViewport,
            currentBreakpoint = config.breakpoints[currentViewport],
            slickConfig = {
                autoplay: $element.data('autoplay'),
                autoplaySpeed: $element.data('autoplay-speed') || 0,
                arrows: $element.data('show-arrows'),
                dots: $element.data('show-dots')
            };

        _.each(config.breakpoints, function (breakpoint) {
            mediaCheck({
                media: breakpointsUtils.buildMedia(breakpoint.conditions),

                /** @inheritdoc */
                entry: function () {
                    initSlider($element, slickConfig, breakpoint);
                }
            });
        });

        //initialize slider when content type is added in mobile viewport
        if (currentViewport === 'mobile') {
            initSlider($element, slickConfig, currentBreakpoint);
        }

        // Redraw slide after content type gets redrawn
        events.on('contentType:redrawAfter', function (args) {
            if ($carouselElement.closest(args.element).length) {
                $carouselElement.slick('setPosition');
            }
        });

        events.on('stage:viewportChangeAfter', function (args) {
            var breakpoint = config.breakpoints[args.viewport];

            initSlider($element, slickConfig, breakpoint);
        });
    };
});
```

app/code/YourVendor/PageBuilderCarousel/view/base/ **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/widget': {
                'YourVendor_PageBuilderCarousel/js/content-type/products/appearance/carousel/widget-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**And now it's time to set the slidesToScroll in our view.xml!**
app\design\frontend\YourVendor\YourTheme\etc\ **view.xml**

add this and adjust your configs

```
<vars module="Magento_PageBuilder">
        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="desktop">
                <var name="label">Desktop</var>
                <var name="stage">true</var>
                <var name="default">true</var>
                <var name="class">desktop-switcher</var>
                <var name="icon">Magento_PageBuilder::css/images/switcher/switcher-desktop.svg</var>
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="min-width">1279px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="products">
                        <var name="default">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">4</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">4</var>
                        </var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
            <var name="tablet">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">1279px</var>
                    <var name="min-width">900px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="products">
                        <var name="default">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">3</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">3</var>
                        </var>
                        <var name="continuous">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">3</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">3</var>
                        </var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
            <var name="tablet_small">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">900px</var>
                    <var name="min-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="products">
                        <var name="default">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">2</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">2</var>
                        </var>
                        <var name="continuous">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">2</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">2</var>
                        </var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="label">Mobile</var>
                <var name="stage">true</var>
                <var name="class">mobile-switcher</var>
                <var name="icon">Magento_PageBuilder::css/images/switcher/switcher-mobile.svg</var>
                <var name="media">only screen and (max-width: 768px)</var>
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                    <var name="min-width">640px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="products">
                        <var name="default">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">2</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">2</var>
                        </var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
            <var name="mobile-small">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">640px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="products">
                        <var name="default">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">1.5</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">1</var>
                        </var>
                        <var name="continuous">
                            <var name="slidesToShow">1.5</var>
                            <var name="slidesToScroll">1</var>
                        </var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </vars>
```

run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to enable the module and you're done!